# Capturing network packets using jNetPcap AP

Tags: java

I am trying to capture SIP and RTP trafic in Java. To begin I'm using this code but it still not works for me. I get the error

> Can't read list of devices, error is

without any other instruction or message. I can't find where the problem is exactly!

Please suggest me the solution. This is my code:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<PcapIf> alldevs = new ArrayList<PcapIf>(); // Will be filled with
                                                        // NICs
        StringBuilder errbuf = new StringBuilder(); // For any error msgs
        int r = Pcap.findAllDevs(alldevs, errbuf);
        if (r == Pcap.NOT_OK || alldevs.isEmpty()) {
            System.err.printf("Can't read list of devices, error is %s",
                    errbuf.toString());
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Network devices found:");
        int i = 0;
        for (PcapIf device : alldevs) {
            String description = (device.getDescription() != null) ? device
                    .getDescription() : "No description available";
            System.out.printf("#%d: %s [%s]\n", i++, device.getName(),
                    description);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I solved this problem , thanks.